# Are Interfaces still relevant in MVVM?

Tags: android, interface, android-mvvm

When talking about MVVM (*Model-View-ViewModel*) are Interfaces still relevant?

In MVP, we used to have a "Contract" interface that would guarantee how both sides would behave.

But every example of MVVM I've found so far is not using interfaces, but concrete classes (even in the [Google Basic Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductListViewModel.java)). In this [post](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b), Florina said *[...]This also means that all the interfaces that the MVP pattern requires, are now dropped.*

Even though we now subscribe to streams of events, shouldn't we at least know for sure to what we are subscribing to?

Comment: The Contract class should disappear from MVVM, because it keep View layer reference.